# Want to delete Firebase postSnapshot Value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, snapshot

How to delete `postSnapshot` value in Realtime Database?

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    .getReference()
        .child("users")
        .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
             @Override
             public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                 for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                      if (postSnapshot.child("cart").child(items.getItemSearchableName()).exists()){

                          // Want to delete postSnapshot.child("cart").child(items.getItemSearchableName())

                       }
                 }
          }

            @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
});
```

postSnapshot.child("cart").child(items.getItemSearchableName()).removeValue(); not working.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to delete a specific value from the Realtime Database, you have to call [DatabaseReference#removeValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#removeValue()). Since inside the callback, you don't have an object of type [DatabaseReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference) but an object of type [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot), then you have to call first [DataSnapshot#getRef()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#getRef()) first. In code it should look like this:

```
postSnapshot.child("cart").child(items.getItemSearchableName()).getRef().removeValue();
```

I also recommend you attach a listener to the remove operation, so you can see if something goes wrong.

Comment: Hey Ratnadeep. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?